# Wildcard query on keyword vs. Ngram + multi-match

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, opensearch

So I have some fields which look like these:

> orderId: ABC-DEF-1234
>
> date: 2024-02-24
>
> lastUpdatedTime: 2024-02-24T12:09:48.763-05:00

My users would like to have the functionality that whatever they put in the search bar (say **X**), find them all the documents if any of those fields in a document **contains exactly** the input **X**. So an input like `DE`, `02-24`, `09:48` will all find my example above.

And to come up with the best solution, I basically consider two things:

1. How/what to **index** these fields
2. How/what to construct my **query** on these fields

And to bear in mind, my data will probably have these constraints in production

1. Number of records - I expect it to be **100,000 ~ 500,000**
2. Number of fields need such support as described above - around **10**

After some research I basically have two options in mind:

**1. Index the field as keyword and use [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) (not indexed as wildcard since does not meet [the condition recommended for wildcard (value > 32KB or > 1 million records)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)**

Index time:

- Simply index those terms as keyword

Search time:

- Use a wildcard query `*X*` for each of the fields

*Q: I learned that beginning on `*` should be avoided or performance would take a hit. How bad of the performance are we talking about given my number of records (half a million) and ~10 columns, since I don't have an easy way right now to simulate the number of records that I will have in production?*

**2. Index the field as text with [N-gram analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#analysis-ngram-tokenizer) and use multi-match query**

Index time:

- Index all the fields with N-gram analyzer.
- If I understanding correctly, a N-gram analyzer will tokenize `ABC-DEF-1234` into `A`, `AB`, `ABC`, `DEF-1`, `ABC-DEF-1234`...(all the adjacent substring when with parameter minimum length 1 and maximum length)

Search time:

- Do a multi-match query of user input on all these fields directly

*Q: This seems to increase the index time significantly and also the storage cost for all those tokenized terms. However, if this would outperform option 1 in terms of query performance by a considerable margin, I could probably live with it.*

So if my analysis is correct, I am inclined to Option 2 at the moment. But just want to share to see if there's a better way or a way which better trade off the performance and cost. Also please let me know if any of my assumptions is incorrect. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is quite correct, and you've outlined the trade-offs between the two options properly. The choice may depend on your specific use case. I understand that there is no easy way to conduct thorough testing with realistic data and queries but it will help you to make your decision.

The [wildcard field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.12/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type) can help you optimize wildcard queries.

> Use the wildcard type if you plan to regularly search the field using
> a wildcard or regexp query and meet one of the following criteria:
>
> The field contains more than a million unique values. AND You plan to
> regularly search the field using a pattern with leading wildcards,
> such as *foo or *baz. The field contains values larger than 32KB. AND
> You plan to regularly search the field using any wildcard pattern.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/find-strings-within-strings-faster-with-the-new-elasticsearch-wildcard-field

Answer (score 1):

### Wildcard

It's easy to use `wildcard`

Mapping

```
PUT /multi_search
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "order_id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "date": {
                "type": "date",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "last_updated": {
                "type": "date",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Documents

```
PUT /multi_search/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"order_id": "ABC-DEF-1234", "date": "2024-02-24", "last_updated" : "2024-02-24T12:09:48.763-05:00"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"order_id": "ABC-DEF-1234", "date": "2024-02-25", "last_updated" : "2024-02-24T12:09:48.763-05:00"}
```

Search query

```
GET /multi_search/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "order_id": {
                            "value": "*DE*"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "date.keyword": {
                            "value": "*02-24*"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "last_updated.keyword": {
                            "value": "*09:48*"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "took" : 2,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "skipped" : 0,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : {
            "value" : 1,
            "relation" : "eq"
        },
        "max_score" : 3.0,
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "multi_search",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 3.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "order_id" : "ABC-DEF-1234",
                    "date" : "2024-02-24",
                    "last_updated" : "2024-02-24T12:09:48.763-05:00"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### N-Grams or Pattern Capture

The `n-grams` filter can produce redundant tokens. For example, the date 2024-02-24 is splitted into tokens such as 2024-02-24, 2024-02, 2024, 02, 02-24, 24. Tokens 0, 20, 24-02-2, -02-24 are meaningless. There are another ways

Query for splitting  a date in yyyy-MM-dd into tokens

```
GET /_analyze?filter_path=tokens.token
{
    "tokenizer": "keyword",
    "filter": [
        {
            "type": "pattern_capture",
            "preserve_original": true,
            "patterns": [
                """((\d{4})-(\d{2}))-(\d{2})""",
                """\d{4}-(\d{2}-\d{2})"""
            ]
        }
    ],
    "text": "2024-02-24"
}
```

Response

```
{
    "tokens" : [
        {
            "token" : "2024-02-24"
        },
        {
            "token" : "2024-02"
        },
        {
            "token" : "2024"
        },
        {
            "token" : "02"
        },
        {
            "token" : "02-24"
        },
        {
            "token" : "24"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Mixed way

You can use `wildcard` for identifiers, if you don't know how the user might search for it, and `pattern_capture` for dates.